# Load Groovy script from file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to load a groovy script from file in a new template.
I tried to set the following under "Groovy template transformation":

${SCRIPT, template="cloud_services_jenkins_templates/Cisco Git Component Pom Based Version.template"}

```
Invalid Groovy template
```

groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript10.groovy: 2: unexpected token: SCRIPT @ line 2, column 15.
   send(out,"""${SCRIPT, template="cloud_services_jenkins_templates/Cisco Git Component Pom Based Version.template"} """);
                 ^

1 error

```
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.modeling.impl.SimpleTemplateEngine.parseScript(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:145)
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.modeling.impl.SimpleTemplateEngine.createTemplate(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:131)
at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.modeling.impl.SimpleTemplateEngine.createTemplate(SimpleTemplateEngine.java:125)
at groovy.text.TemplateEngine.createTemplate(TemplateEngine.java:38)
```

any pointers on what is the issue?